# xPages - How to set focus at different times on a page after refreshing

Tags: xpages

I've tried so many different things.  I have an xpages that is refreshed multiple times and based upon the progression of inputs along the way, I want to focus on different fields.  The latest is using an Output Script and the following code, however, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the viewScope variable so it focuses on the first field on the page or no focus at all.  I set the viewScope variable at different times through the progression.

My questions:

1. Where do I put the Output Script since only part of the page shows up at the beginning of the progression.
2. What code can I use to be efficient and recognize the various places to focus?
3. Is there a better way than Output Script?

Here is the code I'm using...

```
var vNextFocus = viewScope.vsNextFocus;
if(vNextFocus == "CustomerName") {
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:CustomerName}").focus();
}
if(vNextFocus == "PONbr") {
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:PONbr}").focus();
}
```

Etc......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a mix of SSJS and CSJS.

Add an `onClientLoad` event to your XPage.
Calculate the client id which should be focused on with
`#{javascript: ...get client id on server side...}` on server side.
Put the result as a string into CSJS code `XSP.getElementById("...").focus()`.
This way the field which is set in viewScope.vsNextFocus gets the focus.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            XSP.getElementById("#{javascript:
                try {
                    getComponent(viewScope.vsNextFocus).getClientId(facesContext);
                } catch(e) {
                    getComponent('inputText1').getClientId(facesContext);
                }
            }").focus();
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    ... your controls ...
</xp:view>
```

Just in case viewScope.vsNextFocus is not set code defaults to field "inputText1".

Comment: Partial refreshes don't work on my xpage so I'm using all full refreshes and for the first couple, I need full because areas of the page are becoming visible as it progresses.  I don't know why the partial refreshes don't work.  Will the code I posted work in the CSJS code?

Comment: OK. I updated my answer completely. Hope it works for you now.

Comment: Knut, I can't thank you enough.  I've tried so many things, probably spent 5+ days just trying to focus on a field and change that focus at different times.  Would you be willing to take a look at my app and makes suggestions to me?  Partial refreshes display some error window quickly, then goes away.  I posted on this error in the past.  Also, the code you posted shows an warning that the double quote was not closed properly?

Comment: Mike, the warning is just in Client Script Editor window because it is not all in one line. You can ignore it as compilation of XPage is successful or you can put all in one line.

Comment: Mike, yes of course I'd look into your app, just contact me.